# Using linked lists and vectors, How can I assign the data of the linked list to my vector and increment

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, while-loop, linked-list

```
struct nodetype
{
    string info;
    nodetype* link;
};
vector<string> THIRDSTEP::FindMovies(string cloc)
{
    int i = 0;
    string chose;
    nodetype *movies;
    nodetype *h = NULL;
    nodetype *c = NULL;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\MP 116\\mov.txt");

    while (i < 10)
    {
            getline(infile, chose, ',');
            movies = new nodetype;
            movies->info = chose;
            movies->link = NULL;
            if (h == NULL)
            {
                h = movies;
                c = movies;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                c->link = movies;
                c = movies;
                i++;
            }
     }
    // displaying the list of movies
    nodetype *temp;
    vector<string> mov(10);
    int j = 0;
    temp = h;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        mov[j] = temp->info;
        temp = temp->link;
        j++;
    }
    return mov;
    infile.close();
}
```

This is my complete code for this function. it works fine until it goes to displaying the list of movies. `temp->info` doesn't go in to `mov[j]` when debugged thus producing no output. I think what i did was correct i just don't understand why `mov[j]` doesn't read `temp->info`.

Comment: show us the definition of `nodetype` and what the `h` is.

Comment: Does the element's amount of temp exceed the size (10) of vector? Try `vector::push_back()`.

Comment: h means the head or the first node. @pkacprzak

Comment: @JRYS how many elements are in the list?

Comment: 10 elements @pkacprzak

Comment: Is that the actual code? Or is it a mock-up?

Comment: @JonathanPotter actual. but this is a part of a program that I am working on

Comment: A common mistake is to pass a vector to a function by *value*, and then wonder why changes made in that function aren't reflected in the original vector, so I just wanted to check you weren't doing that.

Comment: @JonathanPotter i posted the whole function